# Using user input to ask player if they would like to play again. Problem: Loops under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, console

I have created a guessing game in which the user has 6 tries to guess number, in this case 50. After the user has guessed the number correctly they are prompted with the question, Do you want to play again?. If the user types in yes the program runs again. The problem is when the user types no after playing multiple games, they are prompted with the same message multiple times.[see bottom for better example]

I have tried placing in different conditions in the while loops. I think the problem is the code loops to compensates every time the user types in Yes.

```
function start(){
    //var answer = Randomizer.nextInt(1, 100);
    var answer = 50;
    var guess;
    var lastGuess;
    var attempts = 1;

    while(guess != answer){
        guess = readInt("Guess the number. ");

        //if correct
        if(answer == guess){
            println("Correct guess, it took you " + attempts + " tries. ");
            playAgain();

        //if too high    
        }else if(answer < guess){
            if(lastGuess && answer < lastGuess){
                println("Guess was STILL too high. ");
            }else{
            println("Guess was too high. ");
            }
        lastGuess = guess;

        //if too low
        }else if(answer > guess){
            if(lastGuess && answer > lastGuess){
                println("Guess was STILL too low. ");                
            }else{
                println("Guess was to low. ");
            }
        lastGuess = guess;

        }

        //if 6 attempts done
        if(attempts == 6){
            break;
        }

    attempts++;
    }

    //end game at 6 attempts
    if(guess != answer && attempts == 6){
        println("The answer was " + answer + ". You did not guess the number. ");
        playAgain();
    }
}
```

```
function playAgain(){
    var askPlayAgain = "Yes";
    while(askPlayAgain != "No"){
        askPlayAgain = readLine("Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] ");
        if(askPlayAgain == "No"){
            break;
        }
        if(askPlayAgain == "Yes"){
            start();
        }else{
            println("Please type in your response again? ");
            playAgain();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Guess the number. 50
Correct guess, it took you 1 tries.
Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] Yes
Guess the number. 50
Correct guess, it took you 1 tries.
Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] No
game has ended
Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] No
game has ended
```

Expected results:

```
Guess the number. 50
Correct guess, it took you 1 tries.
Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] Yes
Guess the number. 50
Correct guess, it took you 1 tries.
Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] No
game has ended
```

The user is prompted the message the same number of times if they type in no as yes. For example if I played the game 3 times and typed no after the game ends, the prompt will show 3 times in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies again for my totally incorrect (and now deleted) answer I gave earlier. I believe I now understand the true route cause of your issue, and how to fix it:

The reason for the user being prompted multiple times, once for each time they'd previously said "Yes", is that, for every "Yes" answer, you were calling `start()` again. That of course is what you needed to do to restart the game - the cause of the problem isn't that in itself, but that, after the `start` function has run its course (including its call to `playAgain`), you would enter another iteration of the loop in `playAgain`. And this of course means the user is asked again.

So the problem is actually all inside `playAgain`. The cleanest way to fix it is I think to change the way the loop is structured, like so (one way among several):

```
function playAgain(){
    var askPlayAgain;
    while(true){
        askPlayAgain = readLine("Do you want to play again? [Yes/No] ");
        if(askPlayAgain == "No"){
            break;
        }
        else if(askPlayAgain == "Yes"){
            start();
            break;
        }else{
            println("Please type in your response again? ");
        }
    }
}
```

This loop will keep running, and prompting the user, until the user types either `"No"` or `"Yes"` If they type `"No"` the loop will exit without doing anything else, so the program finishes. And if they type `"Yes"` the game will restart. Crucially, although the user will once again be prompted for another game after finishing (that's the `playAgain` call at the end of `start`), once they have said `"No"`, that will be it, because none of the calls to `playAgain` on the stack do anything observable after the user types `"No"`.

Really, although I've tidied the code up a little, the only meaningful change is adding that `break` after the call to `start` - thus preventing the loop from running again.